# Global name not defined when testing python

Tags: python

Im running a python code. After running it the code works well but when test the code it shows

> nameError Global name not defined.

Here is the code

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if type(word)== str:
        for i in word:
            if word.count(i) >1 or word == "":
                return (word, False)
            else:
                return (word, True)
    else:
        raise TypeError ("'{}' should be a string" .format(word))
```

And here is the test code

```
from unittest import TestCase

class IsogramTestCases(TestCase):
  def test_checks_for_isograms(self):
    word = 'abolishment'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, True),
      msg="Isogram word, '{}' not detected correctly".format(word)
    )

  def test_returns_false_for_nonisograms(self):
    word = 'alphabet'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, False),
      msg="Non isogram word, '{}' falsely detected".format(word)
    )

  def test_it_only_accepts_strings(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
      is_isogram(2)
      self.assertEqual(
        'Argument should be a string',
        context.exception.message,
        'String inputs allowed only'
      )
```

Comment: Please add the *correct* error message including the full traceback to your question.

Comment: What is `if type(word) word:` supposed to do? Moreover, `i` is not defined when you execute `is_isogram`. Your function cannot work as is.

Comment: @Faibbus It should result in a SyntaxError.

Comment: Tge error i got is Global name is_isogram is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear, but I will try to answer correctly.

Your `Global name is_isogram is not defined` appends because you didn't import your code in your test file. You have to do `from mycode import is_isogram` for use the test case on your code. Your test can't know where is your function if you didn't tell him.

Another point, your function is_isogram is not doing what you want her to do, see my comment in your code:

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if type(word)== str:
        for i in word:  # You did a loop here, but...
               # You go out this loop at the first iteration!
            if word.count(i) >1 or word == "":  # Here
                return (word, False)
            else:
                return (word, True)  # Or here
    # You only test the first letter in your word.. You have to move the 
    # return (word, True) outside the loop
    else:
        raise TypeError ("'{}' should be a string" .format(word))
```

Your test case work because alphabet as 2 'a' and the 'a' is in the first position. But if you try with 'lesson' your test will return True, and it shouldn't.

A solution could be:

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if type(word) is str:
        for i in word: 
            if word.count(i) > 1:
                return (word, False)
        return (word, True)
    else:
        raise TypeError("'{}' should be a string" .format(word))
```

Comment: Yes, i just observe now. I intend looping word to get if alphabets occur more than one. Can u please  help me rewrite the code as im still getting error.

Comment: You have to put the `return(word, True)` outside the loop, I will edit my answer with example of code.

Answer (score 0):

well I think you should do a `word.strip()==""` to make sure the condition always check for empty strings. I think your code should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your function is in the same file as your test file (before your test class) or it is being imported from another file. That way, you shouldn't get a **NameError** error. 
Then, try running the tests and post any further errors or issues you may get.